# Vertica: "RESULTS ALL ROWS"

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm using Vertica's MATCH clause, which the Vertica SQL Reference Manual describes as "A SQL extension that lets you screen large amounts of historical data in search of event patterns, the MATCH clause provides subclasses for analytic partitioning and ordering and matches rows from the result table based on a pattern you define."

In the examples in the Programmer's Guide, there's a phrase `RESULTS ALL ROWS` that appears in examples, like this:

```
SELECT uid,
       sid,
       ts,
       refurl,
       pageurl,
       action,
       event_name(),
       pattern_id(),
       match_id()
FROM clickstream_log
MATCH
  (PARTITION BY uid, sid ORDER BY ts
   DEFINE
     Entry AS RefURL NOT ILIKE '%website2.com%' AND PageURL ILIKE '%website2.com%',
     Onsite AS PageURL ILIKE '%website2.com%' AND Action='V',
     Purchase AS PageURL ILIKE '%website2.com%' AND Action = 'P'
   PATTERN
     P AS (Entry Onsite* Purchase)
   RESULTS ALL ROWS);
```

However, I cannot find a defition of what `RESULTS ALL ROWS` does.  Disturbingly, it affects the output, but in some subtle way.  (Meaning, it takes quite a few rows to hit a difference.)

Anyone knows what this phrase actually does?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that is a legacy statement. In v6.1 it has been replaced with [ROW MATCH (ALL EVENTS | FIRST EVENT)](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#15759.htm)

Defines how to resolve more than one event evaluating to true for a single row.

If you use ROWS MATCH ALL EVENTS (default), HP Vertica returns the following run-time error if more than one event evaluates to true for a single row:

ERROR: pattern events must be mutually exclusive

HINT: try using ROWS MATCH FIRST EVENT
For ROWS MATCH FIRST EVENT, if more than one event evaluates to true for a single row, HP Vertica chooses the event defined first in the SQL statement to be the event it uses for the row.